# Row_Number in Select query with Distinct result

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012, distinct, row-number

I have a query in SQL Server 2012:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    FIELD_1, FIELD_2
FROM 
    TABLE_A
```

Now I want to get row number for each record. So I have used `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this purpose.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FIELD_1, FIELD_2) AS rowId
    FIELD_1, FIELD_2
FROM 
    TABLE_A
```

This query does not give me distinct result.
How to retrieve distinct result with row number ?

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `DISTINCT` you should not forget that it will apply after window functions like `ROW_NUMBER` that makes all your rows unique.

So try this:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FIELD_1, FIELD_2) AS rowId,
    FIELD_1, FIELD_2
FROM 
    TABLE_A
GROUP BY
    FIELD_1, FIELD_2
```

Answer (score 1):

try to this

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FIELD_1, FIELD_2) AS rowId
FIELD_1, FIELD_2
FROM (select DISTINCT FIELD_1, FIELD_2 TABLE_A ) a
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but sub-query will reduce performance of application. So I have to find any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting `DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER()`. The row numbers will obviously be unique (e.g. distinct), so this won't really work for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to retrieve distinct data and apply row number on those records.